# Blender 2.78 - Bendy bones - Equal vertex deformation

Tags: armature, bones

In the image below, I applied an armature with bendy bones to a well subdivided tube mesh. When I deform the bendy bones, the mesh follows well, but vertices are bound to the number of bendy bones subdivisions. This leads to deformation gaps (orange in the image). I would like my mesh to be deformed equally (pink in the image).

Is there an easy way to achieve this result?

[image: bendy bones deformation gaps]

Comment: I also am experiencing a similar problem.  Different meshes may allow different solutions.  You example above seems to have many alternatives because it looks circular.